# Directive's link is not rendering variable in the scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I'm expecting the directive to print the template with the values inside `{{  }}` resolved, but it's not. It's printing out `{{argVal}}` as if it's a literal piece of HTML string.

```
myApp.directive('myArgs', [function() {

    var theTemplate = 
        '<span>{</span>' + 
            '<div ng-if="typeIsArray(argVal)">'+
                '<p>{{argVal}}</p>'
                '<my-args arg-val="argVal[0]"></my-args>'
            '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            argVal: '='
        },
        controller: ... //contains utils to check type of argVal
        link: function(scope, element){
            alert(scope.argVal);
            element.html('').append(theTemplate);
        }
      };        
}]);
```

In my HTML file, I'm simply calling the directive like this:

```
<my-args arg-val="someArray"></my-args>
```

(`someArray` is defined in the controller as `$scope.someArray = ["ola", "hi", "bonjour"];`)

`someArray` is definitely in the scope because the `alert(someArray)` is working.

So why won't the template portion render properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the template with scope

```
element.html('').append(theTemplate);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

And dont forget to provide dependency $compile to directive.

Comment: If you are using dynamic template then angular is not rendering it with directive and doesn't know the scope so you must compile it with some scope and render it in angular way.But it you are directly provide this to template:'<div>{{xyz}}</div>' it is considered as static template and render with directive scope while compiling template itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should not append the template to the element directly. Use the directive's template attribute like this:

```
    myApp.directive('myArgs', [function() {

    var theTemplate = 
        '<span>{</span>' + 
            '<div ng-if="typeIsArray(argVal)">'+
                '<p>{{argVal}}</p>'
                '<my-args arg-val="argVal[0]"></my-args>'
            '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            argVal: '='
        },
        controller: ... //contains utils to check type of argVal
        template: theTemplate,  // this will eval correctly
        link: function(scope, element){
            alert(scope.argVal);

            // this is not needed
            //element.html('').append(theTemplate);
        }
      };        
}]);
```

Comment: it is because you were using dynamic template now it is static and comipled by directive itself.If you need dynamic template you need to compile it maually by $compile.

Comment: Wait, now it's static or dynamic? I thought it was dynamic. Do I NEED `$compile` or can I just use your way?

Comment: You should use the template attribute if at all possible. Only use $compile inside your link fn if you are dynamically generating the template on the fly.